# How to mock a class and its attributes at the same time

Tags: python, mocking

I have a class `ClassA` which is a list of `ClassB.element` objects. See below

```
class ClassA:

    element = []

    def __init__(self, data_object):

        for content in data_object.objects:
            element.append(ClassB(content).element)

class ClassB:

    element = ""

    def __init__(self, content)
        ...
```

I am currently trying to create a unit test for the `__init__` method of `ClassA`, but I don't want it to rely on `ClassB` and for that matter on `data_object.objects`. What I would like to achieve is for `ClassB(content).element` to return a predefined list of values, e.g. ["foo", "bar"]. So I would get something like

```
def test_class_a_init():
    class_a_obj = ClassA(data_object=MagicMock())
    ...
    assert class_a_obj.element == ["foo", "bar"]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why don't you want to create instances of `ClassB`? It's `__init__` method should be simple and cheap; if it's not, you probably want to define a class method or factory function to do the expensive work of computing or fetching the arguments for `ClassB.__init__`.

Comment: Or, you might break the dependence of `ClassA` on `ClassB` by making the *caller* responsible for passing a list of `ClassB` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent written all of your code to make this work, so I assume your classes look like this:

```
class ClassA:

    element = []

    def __init__(self, data_object):
        for content in data_object.objects:
            self.element.append(ClassB(content).element)

class ClassB:

    element = ""

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.element=content
```

In which case, you can do:

```
class MagicMock:
    objects = ["foo", "bar"]


class_a_obj = ClassA(data_object=MagicMock())
assert class_a_obj.element == ["foo", "bar"]
```

Do remove the dependency of ClassB, you can use dependency injection in ClassA:

```
from typing import Type

class ClassB:

    element = ""

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.element=content


class ClassA:

    element = []

    def __init__(self, data_object, child_obj: Type[ClassB] = ClassB):
        for content in data_object.objects:
            self.element.append(child_obj(content).element)
```